# Difference between transactions and raw transactions in web3.js

Tags: transactions, web3js, raw-transaction

Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethaccounts) of **web3.js** I have come across sending [transactions](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) and [raw transactions](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction).In the documentation it's specified that send raw transaction sends an already signed transaction.

Does this imply that **web3.js** does not sign transactions when **sendTransaction()** is called?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All transactions need to be signed.  Otherwise they are considered invalid transactions and will not be included in the blockchain.

A raw transaction is a transaction in raw bytes.  If one has the raw bytes of a valid transaction, they can use `sendRawTransaction`.  Otherwise, web3.js creates the signed transaction's bytes for you automatically as part of `sendTransaction()`.  web3.js converts the JSON transaction `{from:..., to:..., value:...}` to the raw bytes and signs it for you automatically.

Raw bytes are required if you are using a platform like infura.io which does not handle private keys but deal only with signed transactions.

Comment: I asked a related / follow up question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18928/what-is-a-raw-transaction-and-what-is-it-used-for

Comment: @Tesa Thanks.  I will try to write a good answer for it (someone fast has already written one), might take few days.