# How to use sendrawtransaction properly

Tags: go-ethereum

```
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/root@123", request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))
```

when I used this then `sendTransaction` is not working . I have to use `sendRawTransaction` . I want to use this 2 addresses for `sendRawTransaction` <kbd>0x33e9d80d9209a00B3F953748Bd59D68b4c7c7B91</kbd> , <kbd>0x72f5445cd31D7B6dedBBCDD425A558aeEa4B3acE</kbd> .

Now how could I use this ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `sendRawTransaction` you need pass the transaction signed and in raw bytes. The posts [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/difference-between-transactions-and-raw-transactions-in-web3-js) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18928/what-is-a-raw-transaction-and-what-is-it-used-for) will give a good understanding about the difference between the two methods.

> I want to use this 2 addresses for `sendRawTransaction`
>
> <kbd>0x33e9d80d9209a00B3F953748Bd59D68b4c7c7B91</kbd> ,
>   <kbd>0x72f5445cd31D7B6dedBBCDD425A558aeEa4B3acE</kbd> .
>
> Now how could I use this ?

To use `sendRawTransaction`,signing and getting the raw bytes can be done as explained [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction).

> ```
> var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
> var privateKey = new Buffer('e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109','hex')
>
> var rawTx = {
>   nonce: '0x00',
>   gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', 
>   gasLimit: '0x2710',
>   to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
>   value: '0x00', 
>   data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
> }
>
> var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
> tx.sign(privateKey);
>
> var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
>
> //console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'));
> //0xf889808609184e72a00082271094000000000000000000000000000000000000000080a47f74657374320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000571ca08a8bbf888cfa37bbf0bb965423625641fc956967b81d12e23709cead01446075a01ce999b56a8a88504be365442ea61239198e23d1fce7d00fcfc5cd3b44b7215f
>
> web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
>   if (!err)
>     console.log(hash); // "0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead79fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91385"
> });
> ```

And [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/create-and-sign-offline-raw-transactions) will also be useful.

Hope this helps!

Comment: where I give "from address" ??

Comment: you can have the from field set inside rawTx

Comment: you my refer [this](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/5039/how-to-use-web3-js-to-sign-a-contract-call) forum post as well

Comment: if you tried above and getting any errors, post the errors here

Comment: can you tell the python version of "sendrawtransaction" ??

Comment: check [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.sendRawTransaction)

Comment: @TusharSubhraBose did you get your problem solved?