# Method personal_sign not supported

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereumjs

I'm trying to use `personal_sign` and getting not supported error. I'm using web3 v 0.20.1

I first tried using infura and was not able to resolve the issue, so then I connected to a geth node with this setup: `geth --rpc --rpcport "8434" --rpccorsdomain "*" --ipcdisable --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 4`

I've not been able to understand how to access this `personal_sign` method despite being able to access the web3.currentProvider object.

**Edit - seems to now be solved with version 1.0.0 + if the personal flag is set for rpcapi. Is there any way to set this flag when using infura?

Answer (score 1):

To use Infura with web3 v0.20 and to be able to sign transaction you need a provider engine.

- MetaMask's provider engine https://github.com/MetaMask/web3-provider-engine
- Truffle's HD Wallet Provider https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/truffle-hdwallet-provider

Comment: Are these links supposed to be useful? This answer is NOT helpful at all...

Comment: @Jim Those links were valid for web3 v0.20 on April 2019. Web3 is now at v1.5, and Truffle is using a mono repo as of October 2021, so yes the answer is outdated.

Comment: @Jim This answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46002 fixes a similar issue and it updated to web3 v1.0 and it should work with current version.

Comment: Posting links with zero explanation is NOT a good answer. You may want to go read a guide and learn how to do it properly.