# The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available on infura

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, infura

Im trying to send transaction to simple greeter contract with web3.js on infura node.while doing soo, Im getting this error.

```
 throw errors.InvalidResponse(result);
        ^

Error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available
```

after lot of investigation about this error on internet, I came to conclusion that infura doesnt support this method and we have to sign transactions offline and send raw transactions to node. Im already doing the same. but keep getting this error please help me to fix this error..
here is my transaction signing code:

```
const contractFunction = contract.greet({from:web3.eth.defaultAccount},"hello all devs");

const functionAbi = contractFunction.encodeABI();

let estimatedGas;
let nonce;

console.log("Getting gas estimate");

contractFunction.estimateGas({from: account}).then((gasAmount) => {
 estimatedGas = gasAmount.toString(16);

 console.log("Estimated gas: " + estimatedGas);

 web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account).then(_nonce => {
   nonce = _nonce.toString(16);

   console.log("Nonce: " + nonce);
   const txParams = {
     gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
     gasLimit: 3000000,
     to: contract_Address,
     data: functionAbi,
     from: account,
     nonce: '0x' + nonce
   };
   const tx = new Tx(txParams);
   signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, privateKey)
   tx_hash= web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
   tx_receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
   //tx.sign(privateKey);
   console.log(tx_receipt)
```

Comment: `web3.eth.sendRawTransaction` returns a `Promise` object, not a transaction hash. You need to either `await` for it to complete (which means that you'll have to put everything inside an `async` function), or resolve the promise in some other way.

Comment: Can you please provide a code to do that??@goodvibration

Comment: Like I said, add `await` before `web3.eth.sendRawTransaction`, and put the whole thing inside an `async` function.

Comment: https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/

Comment: Still getting  same error.. I will send full code. Plz anyone solve this.. @Majid TL or  goodvibration

Comment: here is my full code https://bitbucket.org/ajay279/web3js/src/master/sign.js. plz anyone fix it and post transaction hash if transaction went through.. @Majid TL 
 or goodvibration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid JSON RPC response error for sendTransaction on Infura + Ropsten node + Truffle console](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26999/invalid-json-rpc-response-error-for-sendtransaction-on-infura-ropsten-node-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dude (this is the third question about the same thing), **I have changed** some methods if you have questions about it write it down please and dont open a new question :)

this is the new code

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/......");
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const account1 = '.......'; // Your account address 1
//const account2 = '' // Your account address 2
web3.eth.defaultAccount = account1;

const privateKey1 = Buffer.from('.......', 'hex');

const abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_greeting","type":"string"}],"name":"greet","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getGreeting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];

const contract_Address = "0xcbe74e21b070a979b9d6426b11e876d4cb618daf";

const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_Address);

const myData = myContract.methods.greet( "hello blockchain devs").encodeABI();

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {
// Build the transaction
  const txObject = {
    nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    to:       contract_Address,
    value:    web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('6', 'gwei')),
    data: myData  
  }
    // Sign the transaction
    const tx = new Tx(txObject);
    tx.sign(privateKey1);

    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');

    // Broadcast the transaction
    const transaction = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, tx) => {
        console.log(tx)
    });
});
```

and this is the proof it work

[image]

Comment: changed : new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_Address) and  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000) and  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction

Comment: now i'm getting an error "TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor". I'm on web3 1.0.0 beta

Comment: are you sure ? I'm using '1.0.0-beta.55' . write this in your code and take a look on the web3 version         " const web3 = new Web3(provider);
console.log(web3.version);"

Comment: @ajay did you fix it?

Comment: Yeah. Thank you @Majid TL. Appreciated your effort..

Comment: I have  already worked with them. I'm planning to create desktop dapp. so it requires minimal use of npm modules.

Comment: okay, good luck :)